# introjs-helperLayer overlay targetElement in intro.js

Tags: javascript, html, intro.js

[Green button whith introJs().start();](http://www.etagi.com/search_on_map/)

Step By Step function is work, but targetElement no aviable.

Please help!

Sorry^ my English = bad

Comment: Can you describe your problem here ? I couldn't see any tutorial behind the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine with using the IntroJs, there's no problem with using.

All I can say is that you should **upload your css files again**, it seems your IntroJs CSS file is broken now.